# Is it possible to create window that larger than the screen?

Tags: wpf

I have an app that I created it increases according to its content. the content width can be different from time to time. When the size of the window become larger than the screen the window get cut.

Is it possible to make a window that larger than the screen?

Comment: I just need to do it. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Are you wanting to have your window inside of a scrollable region?  If that's the case, your window would not actually be larger than the screen, but the content within the window would.

Comment: No I want the window to be larger than the screen

Comment: Are you try to play with MinWidth/MinHeight?

Comment: What do you mean by "play with"? I tried to set it with some value but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding the issue.  Are you setting the width/height to a value larger than the screen, and the area outside of the screen gets cut?  Is there an additional monitor that it should be overflowing onto?

Comment: The size set to auto so it grow and shrink acordding to the content.
But you can assume that I set the width with value that larger than the screen and the area out side of the screen gets cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is possible:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="2000" Width="5000" Left="-10" Top="-10">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Okay, I think you want to do it dynamically, right? I could think of some code behind to check the content size and set the window size.

(although I don't like what you want to achieve) ;)

Comment: This is a good solution in case I manually insert the height and width. But how can I do it if the height and width is auto.
Do I need to write some code in the SizeChanged event?

Comment: @Alex - Have you tried making the MaxHeight and MaxWidth properties really big?

Comment: You can use the DesiredSize property of a control. Everytime you change your content you get this size and can use it to change the size of the window.

Comment: It doesn't work for newer version of windows. Such as windows 10.

Comment: If you want DesiredSize to be updated after a content change, you should call the `Measure` method.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF I can create a window larger than the screen dynamically with the following:

```
        var window = new Window();
        window.Width = 8620;
        window.Height = 400;

        window.Top = 400;
        window.Left = 0;

        window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        window.AllowsTransparency = true;
        window.Show();
```

I know that it works because if I hook up a second monitor and extend it the window is visible (put a border - set the WindowStyle, change the background color, or show content to see the window).